# Why should systems record, in the database, who has logged in and when? Compliance, security, auditability?

Tags: sql, database-design

Sorry to mis-tag this SQL, but you seem like an active bunch here.  I'm a data warehouse developer, currently working for a company that has developed an in-house bespoke operational system that I am extracting data from into the data warehouse.  Some users asked if I could include user logging information in the warehouse - who logged in and when.  But the system does not store this information.  I feel like it should. Are there compliance / regulatory rules saying it should?  Are there good security / system reasons why it should?

Comment: I should add that this is not a finance system - but it contains sensitive information about clients and prices that would be very useful to a competitor.

Comment: If it contains sensitive information perhaps they are after things like who edited what, such as, if you worked for a planes part manufacturer, a plane went down and a defect may have been known, if they removed that to make out company isnt at fault.. people would want to be able to prove there was no tampering.

Comment: Reporting? For some companies, the board of directors may want to look at user logins - i.e who are logging in to their website, how often, and for how long. Auditing is the most simple and obvious reason. Customers often report issues that auditing can prove was a customer problem as opposed to a system bug. Not sure of any "rules", would the ISO 27001 compliance fit here?

Comment: Thanks Arran - the system is poor - it doesn't keep track of changed - it physically deletes records rather than marking it as old and creating a new one, and overwrites records during edits.  I have persuaded them to implement change data control in Oracle so these changes are tracked.  I can tell who did what and when.  What I can't do is determine who logged in and when. Will take a look at ISO 27001.

Answer (score 1):

The system should store an audit log somewhere. It is best if it is stored in a separate database to non-security data or otherwise kept separate.

The audit log is used to observe user behaviour as part of non-repudiation. It is the only way of policing the behavior of administrators and other users with few restrictions. Many organizations will require an audit log for compliance with SOX (Sarbanes-Oxley), HIPAA, PCI-DSS or supply-chain contracts.

The audit log should have some form of simple tamper detection, such as a HMAC. Operations to purge or backup old audit log entries should also add an entry to the audit log.

[Edit: Added more details on request]

Non-repudiation is a very fancy way of saying "You can't claim you didn't do it" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation). For example, if a user uploads troublesome data then claims it was not him or her, an audit log showing the fact that the user logged on when no one else was would be very useful.

An HMAC is a Hashed Message Authentication Code (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code or http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt). This is a cryptographic algorithm where you have a secret number, append it to the data and take a hash. This might be difficult to calculate without libraries and is probably a bit ahead of where you want to be.

Comment: Thanks akton - as it's not a finacial system, not sure how relevant SOX etc are.  Please explain non-repudiation and HMAC a little?

Comment: I have added more to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Some industries and countries do have regulation around auditing; SOX widened that considerably. However, as far as I know, there's no general legislation or regulation about this - which is probably a good thing.

However, the fact that users are asking for reports on this data suggests there's a need to collect it.

Other reasons for storing this sort of data is to understand usage (and possibly bill departments for that usage), detect bugs, support capacity management and monitor service quality. Most non-trivial enterprise applications need at least some of those capabilities, even if they don't require formal audit.

If data security is your concern - protecting your prices and customer lists - audit alone is nowhere near enough, and may well be counter productive. Tracking a data leak to an individual log-in is almost certainly going to be (nearly) impossible, and could easily end up accusing the wrong person.